# Firebase - update() value in database

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to `update()` a value inside of my firebase database, but I'm struggling.

I first did:

```
  this.database.list('/replies/'+this.postData.parent+'/'+this.postData.id).update('score', this.voteCount)
```

Thinking that would work, but I got an error:

> ERROR Error: Reference.update failed: First argument  must be an object containing the children to replace.

I then tried:

```
this.database.list('/replies/'+this.postData.parent+'/'+this.postData.id).update({'score': this.voteCount})
```

with `this.voteCount` being an integer.

and I got the following error:

> ERROR Error: Expects a string, snapshot, or reference. Got: object

I'm really confused as to why it's first asking for an object and then later tells me it doesn't want an object..

If I change `update()` to `set()` and keep it as `('score', this.voteCount)` it works fine, but I don't want to set it, I want to update it if it exists..

Am I doing something wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
this.database.ref('/replies/'+this.postData.parent+'/'+this.postData.id).update({'score': this.voteCount})
```

Comment: Yes, thank you that worked. For me I had to do `this.database.database.ref`. Appreciate it!